# Angular 2 subject is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to communicate with 2 components
I thought I'd be able to make a http call, then maybe mergeMap or switchMap to a subject?

Something like

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.populateList = new Subject<Blog[]>();
 }

getBlogs(){
  return this._http.get(this.blogsURL+'blogs')
       .map((result: Response ) => {
       this.blogs = result['blogs'];
    return this.blogs;
  }).switchMap((blogs)=>this.populateList.next(blogs))
}
```

But I get:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
>   an Observable, Promise, Array

I'm getting errors just trying to subscribe to the subject:

```
 this.blogsService.populateList()
      .subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
  })
```

> this.blogsService.populateList is not a function

What I'm looking for is a way to update views after http calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe like this without (). Cause its not a function. surprise

```
 this.blogsService.populateList.subscribe()
```

and rewrite first function like this cause you dont need switch map you just need to do is side effect to populate list.

```
getBlogs(){
  return this._http.get(this.blogsURL+'blogs')
       .map((result: Response ) => {
       this.blogs = result['blogs'];
    return this.blogs;
  }).do((blogs)=>this.populateList.next(blogs))
}
```

Comment: Now I get ".do is not a function", also I've subscribed to Subjects before in the manner I've shown and had no problems

Comment: have you imported 'rxjs/add/operator/do'

Comment: Ah yes that worked in regards to the do function, but still getting populateList errors

Comment: i hope you initated populateList in service: public populateList

Comment: I see it now!! the parenthesis, I must be tired...thanks

Comment: No problem. Happens to all of us :-)